# What is the best practice of rendering list of objects in React and why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Passing the full object into the component?

```js
{list.map(
  (item => (
    <Child item={item} key={item.id} />
  )
)}
```

Or using destructuring?

```js
{list.map(
  (({id, prop1, prop2, prop3}) => (
    <Child key={id} prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} prop3={prop3} />
  )
)}
```

Maybe TypeScript can change or add the new approach somehow?

Answer (score 1):

There is no best option, as it depends on your use case. But there  are subtle differences:

In second case,

1. it would be a lot easier to optimize using `React.memo`, as react compares props and decide whether it should re-render. Passing an object (which would probably be created fresh in every render) would defeat the purpose and you would have to write extra logic to fix it.

In first case,

1. `Child` can mutate `item` by mistake. You probably do not want that. This does not look like great abstraction.
2. the code is much shorter and it does make sense, when the whole object `item` changes together and then extracting individual prop like `prop1`,`prop2`,`prop3` do not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tushar Shai, that it depends on your use case.

Also consider that when you pass the full object `item={item}`, the child component **will not rerender** when only a property, say prop1, of item has changed, whereas in your second proposition the Child-component would rerender and display the changed property.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can automatically deconstruct and use all the values inside the item
like this:

```
{list.map(
  (item => (
    <Child key={item.id} {...item} />
  )
)}
```

and in the child component, you can get all the data inside item

```
const Child =({prop1, prop2, prop3, ...}) =>{
 // your code
}
```